# When multiple messages occur across same date how can I tag the first one as induced?

Tags: python, dataframe, jupyter

I have a large dataframe of car maintenance messages.  I am trying to scrub this data and remove all messages that are induced.

Any time car message 44 appears, my code tags all messages that appear at the same time as induced.  I am trying to invert my logic so any time message 44 appears with another message, it is marked as induced.

I have it filtered so the first message of any date that appears will be message 44.

My code as it stands:

```
df['MsgCat'] = 'New'
for i in range(1,len(df)):
    if df['MsgCat'].iloc[i] == 'New':
        if df['CarSerial'].iloc[i] == df['CarSerial'].iloc[i-1]:
            if df['Date'].iloc[i] == df['Date'].iloc[i-1]:
               df['MsgCount'].iloc[i] = df['MsgCount'].iloc[i-1] + 1
               if df['MsgId'].iloc[i-((df['MsgCount'].iloc[i])-1)] == 1:
                  df['MsgCat'].iloc[i] = 'Induced'   
            else:
                df['MsgCount'].iloc[i] = 1
        else:
            df['MsgCount'].iloc[i] = 1
    else:
        df['MsgCount'].iloc[i] = 1
```

Output:

```
CarSerial     Date          MessageNum       MsgId     MsgCount   MsgCat
015           10/14/2015    44               1         1          New
015           10/14/2015    21               2         2          Induced
015           10/14/2015    22               3         3          Induced
015           10/20/2015    30               5         1          New
022           5/1/2015      44               1         1          New 
022           7/10/2015     44               1         1          New 
022           1/4/2016      44               1         1          New
141           1/10/2016     17               9         1          New
141           1/10/2016     18               10        2          New
008           1/21/2016     44               1         1          New
008           2/4/2016      44               1         1          New
008           2/4/2016      30               5         2          Induced
008           2/4/2016      31               6         3          Induced
```

DESIRED Output:

```
CarSerial     Date          MessageNum       MsgId     MsgCount   MsgCat
015           10/14/2015    44               1         1          Induced
015           10/14/2015    21               2         2          New
015           10/14/2015    22               3         3          New
015           10/20/2015    30               5         1          New
022           5/1/2015      44               1         1          New 
022           7/10/2015     44               1         1          New 
022           1/4/2016      44               1         1          New
141           1/10/2016     17               9         1          New
141           1/10/2016     18               10        2          New
008           1/21/2016     44               1         1          New
008           2/4/2016      44               1         1          Induced
008           2/4/2016      30               5         2          New
008           2/4/2016      31               6         3          New
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How big is the dataframe? Is it pandas?

Comment: Roughly 10,000 lines. Yes, it is pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Good puzzle!

Group the rows by `CarSerial` and `Date`. For each group record whether it has a `MessageNum` of 44 in it and more than one row by adding an item to a dictionary called `changes`. The item in the dictionary consists of a class based on the `dict` class which assigns 'Induced' to 44 and 'New' to everything else. Thus, any of the groups matching the criteria will be represented by an item in the `changes` dictionary that assigns the `MsgCat` label you want, for the records that must change. Use the `change_if_need_be` function to examine the contents of each row by looking it up in `changes` and assigning a result, for both the records includes in `changes` and all others.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', sep='\s+')
>>> df
    CarSerial        Date  MessageNum  MsgId  MsgCount
0          15  10/14/2015          44      1         1
1          15  10/14/2015          21      2         2
2          15  10/14/2015          22      3         3
3          15  10/20/2015          30      5         1
4          22    5/1/2015          44      1         1
5          22   7/10/2015          44      1         1
6          22    1/4/2016          44      1         1
7         141   1/10/2016          17      9         1
8         141   1/10/2016          18     10         2
9           8   1/21/2016          44      1         1
10          8    2/4/2016          44      1         1
11          8    2/4/2016          30      5         2
12          8    2/4/2016          31      6         3
>>> grouping = df.groupby(df['CarSerial'].apply(lambda n: str(n)) + ' ' + df['Date'])
>>> class Once(dict):
...     def __missing__(self, key):
...         return 'New'
...     
>>> once = Once()
>>> once[44] = 'Induced'
>>> def change_if_need_be(row):
...     key = str(row['CarSerial'])+' '+row['Date']
...     if key in changes:
...         return changes[key][row['MessageNum']]
...     else:
...         return 'New'
...     
>>> changes = {}
>>> for g in grouping:
...     if any(g[1].MessageNum == 44) and g[1].MessageNum.count()>1:
...         changes[g[0]] = once
... 
>>> df['MsgCat'] = df.apply(change_if_need_be, axis=1)
>>> df
    CarSerial        Date  MessageNum  MsgId  MsgCount   MsgCat
0          15  10/14/2015          44      1         1  Induced
1          15  10/14/2015          21      2         2      New
2          15  10/14/2015          22      3         3      New
3          15  10/20/2015          30      5         1      New
4          22    5/1/2015          44      1         1      New
5          22   7/10/2015          44      1         1      New
6          22    1/4/2016          44      1         1      New
7         141   1/10/2016          17      9         1      New
8         141   1/10/2016          18     10         2      New
9           8   1/21/2016          44      1         1      New
10          8    2/4/2016          44      1         1  Induced
11          8    2/4/2016          30      5         2      New
12          8    2/4/2016          31      6         3      New
```

Edit: I've thought of a refinement that will run faster.

Change the function to this.

```
>>> def change_if_need_be(row):
...     key = str(row['CarSerial'])+' '+row['Date']
...     if key in changes:
...         return once[row['MessageNum']]
...     else:
...         return 'New'
...
```

Change `changes` from a `dict` to a list like this.

```
>>> changes = []
>>> for g in grouping:
...     if any(g[1].MessageNum == 44) and g[1].MessageNum.count()>1:
...         changes.append(g[0])
...
```

**Edit**: Simplified (elimination of `class` derived from `dict`) and consolidated.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.read_csv('cars.csv', sep='\s+')
>>> df
    CarSerial        Date  MessageNum  MsgId  MsgCount   MsgCat
0          15  10/14/2015          44      1         1      New
1          15  10/14/2015          21      2         2  Induced
2          15  10/14/2015          22      3         3  Induced
3          15  10/20/2015          30      5         1      New
4          22    5/1/2015          44      1         1      New
5          22   7/10/2015          44      1         1      New
6          22    1/4/2016          44      1         1      New
7         141   1/10/2016          17      9         1      New
8         141   1/10/2016          18     10         2      New
9           8   1/21/2016          44      1         1      New
10          8    2/4/2016          44      1         1      New
11          8    2/4/2016          30      5         2  Induced
12          8    2/4/2016          31      6         3  Induced
>>> grouping = df.groupby(df['CarSerial'].apply(lambda n: str(n)) + ' ' + df['Date'])
>>> changes = []
>>> for g in grouping:
...     if any(g[1].MessageNum == 44) and g[1].MessageNum.count()>1:
...         changes.append(g[0])
... 
>>> def change_if_need_be(row):
...     key = str(row['CarSerial'])+' '+row['Date']
...     if key in changes:
...         return {44: 'Induced'}.get(row['MessageNum'], 'New')
...     else:
...         return 'New'
... 
>>> df['MsgCat'] = df.apply(change_if_need_be, axis=1)
```

Results the same.

Answer (score -1):

Simply inverting the logic isn't enough: you've already passed up message 44 when you discover that it was induced.  You have two basic choices:

1. Save the index and date of the most recent message 44.  When you find another message, if the date matches, mark the 44 message as induced.  Either way, reset (clear) the held index and date.
2. Work from the end of the list.  Always save the most recent date (previous message).  Every time you hit a 44 message, just check whether the date matches the previous one.  If it does, mark this one as induced.